# Connecting to VPN Network in Ubuntu

Tags: vpn, cisco

I am trying to connect to a VPN from a Linux PC.  Now, this works on a Windows PC, where

- we use Cisco AnyConnect as the VPN client
- we use RSA SecurID Software Tokens
- the token is a soft token, using a sdtid file

So, this works on my Windows PC, using windows applications & instructions.  I would like to also connect to this VPN from a laptop I have running Ubuntu

I've installed openConnect, and I've also installed stoken to handle the RSA passcodes for openConnect.

However, when I attempt to import my sdtid file into stoken, I get this error

```
me@Animal:~/Cat/VPN$ stoken import --file filename.sdtid 
error: no valid token in file 'filename.sdtid': General failure
```

I've googled around and also tried something called TokenConverter (a Java application) to convert data from the sdtid to a code that can be entered into stoken, but it hangs when I try to run it.

My sdtid file looks to be an XML file, not a binary file.

I'm using version 0.2-1 of stoken (as that's what the ubuntu repositories installed), but it looks like there are later versions downloadable.

Has anyone got this setup to work from Ubuntu?  Surely I just must be missing a step.  Thanks for any help.

Here's what I see when I add a connection:

[image: Network Manager's *Add VPN Connection* dialog box]

There's no option to use a soft token.

Edit: After running software updater, stoken has been updated to 0.8. And it looks like the VPN connection is displaying the field to load from the soft id. I did end up finding the version of the VPN Connection where I could add the softid details, but then corporate policy changed where I was unable to use my own hardware to connect. So I never completed this successfully.

Comment: I was able to upgrade stoken to 0.6, and it seemed happier with the sdtid file (it didn't complain as above, anyways).  But I don't seem to be able to configure my VPN connection to use stoken. ??

Comment: `stoken` devs have a PPA: https://launchpad.net/~cernekee/+archive/ppa - you could try adding that and using v0.6 of `stoken`.

Comment: According to Software Center, I'm using v 0.6  (version 0.6-1ppa~trusty)... is that the right version?

Comment: looking at the PPA page, I think so. No luck with that version?

Comment: None.  I wish I knew how to link a screenshot, but I'm not seeing anything that allows me to select a softid :/

Comment: post on imgur and add a link. A mod can add it, or i could suggest an edit.

Comment: OK,this is a link to imgur which shows what I see when I try to define a vpn connection.  I thought I saw something online that there should be a field at the bottom that allows you to select the softkey from stoken, but I don't see anything on my page: http://imgur.com/VoXrrSZ

Comment: After running software updater, stoken has been updated to 0.8. And it looks like the VPN connection is displaying the field to load from the soft id. Hopefully I can progress now.

Comment: Did you get it working? I updated to the PPA packages and I still don't see a soft ID option in the NM dialog.

Comment: I did not.  I did end up finding the version of the VPN Connection where I could add the softid details, but then corporate policy changed where I was unable to use my own hardware to connect.  So I never completed this successfully.

Comment: Added info from comment on answer to the question - It seems the problem went away after routine upgrade, but OP could not verify because their workplace policy changed

Answer (score 0):

Try install OpenVPN and configure with Network Manager:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome    
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Then, open the Network Manager and add a new VPN Connection.

See this links:

- http://torguard.net/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=53
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient

Comment: I've done this, but I'm still not seeing how I can associate my openconnect vpn with something that uses my sdtid file or something like stoken.  ???